# Handle ALL events in one handler?

Tags: vb.net, events, event-handling

Is it possible in VB.NET to easily write an event handler that will handle every event that fires?  I'm wondering if one could make a logging system using something like this.

I'm wanting to do something like (in pseudocode):

```
Public Sub eventHandledEvent(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    File.Write(sender.EventName)
End Sub
```

I realize it would be slow, but it wouldn't be for a production system, only as a development tool.

Comment: Can you supply a code example of what you are looking to do?

Comment: If you handle every event in VB, you will slow your system to a crawl. WM_PAINT fires thousands of times per second for instance.

Comment: I wasn't even sure if it is feasible, but it could be useful for debugging purposes when performance doesn't matter too much.

Comment: It should be possible to do this with reflection? Find all the events, and add handlers for them all? Anyone have any code for that.

Comment: Obviously no one does. OK, I will have to answer the question myself :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859902/in-3-minutes-what-is-reflection). Here's how. Create a form with a textbox called `TextBox1`. Paste the following code. Run the project and look at the immediate window.

```
Public Class Form1

  Private Sub Form1_Activated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Activated
    RegisterAllEvents(TextBox1, "MyEventHandler")
  End Sub

  Sub MyEventHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Debug.WriteLine("An event has fired: sender= " & sender.ToString & ", e=" & e.ToString)
  End Sub
  Sub RegisterAllEvents(ByVal obj As Object, ByVal methodName As String)
    'List all events through reflection'
    For Each ei As System.Reflection.EventInfo In obj.GetType().GetEvents()
      Dim handlerType As Type = ei.EventHandlerType
      Dim method As System.Reflection.MethodInfo = Me.GetType().GetMethod(methodName)
      'Create a delegate pointing to the method'
      Dim handler As [Delegate] = [Delegate].CreateDelegate(handlerType, Me, method)
      'Register the event through reflection'
      ei.AddEventHandler(obj, handler)
    Next
  End Sub
End Class
```

This is from Francesco Balena's book [Programming Microsoft Visual Basic 2005 The Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735621837). The techique works with any object that raises events, not just controls. It uses [contravariance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724919/understanding-covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-4-0).

If you [buy the book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735621837), there's a full explanation and some more code which will allow you to identify which event has fired in the universal handler, and use regular expressions to handle only a subset of events. I don't feel I can post such a long excerpt here.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: Adjusted due to Hans' comment.

No problem, at least for some events, since it's already built in for the events that send out messages. Just look at [Control.WndProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc.aspx). All messages to the window will go through there.

Comment: +1 spot on. However for any child controls you will have to subclass them, then use the subclassed versions. E.g., Public Class MyTextBox/Inherits Textbox/Overrides WndProc (code...)/end class. CALL A WORKER SUB don't put code in the WndProcs. Pass it the Message and control.name. FILTER THE MESSAGES based on what you care about; most, you wont.

Comment: Not really.  Lots of events don't have a Window message associated with them.  AutoSizeChanged, BackColorChanged, BindingContextChanged, etc, etc.  But it's about as practical as it gets.

Comment: Obviously this only covers controls not *all* events.

Comment: This technique works, for controls which have a window, but why not just use Spy++ or Winspector? http://www.softpedia.com/get/Security/Security-Related/Winspector.shtml Why reinvent the wheel?